# How to write a custom module for spring data

Tags: spring-data

I need to extend spring data in order to support my own custom backend. From the [spring data website](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data/), it seems that it is possible to add community modules to the framework, which in turn enables you to support a custom backend. However, I can't seem to find some code examples/docs illustrating the module implementation mechanism.

Even a basic example using a file-based persistence would be very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to extend it then you can override the methods and add your own. If you're using IntelliJ, just implement/extend (for example) CrudRepository, execute `Generate Code` and select `Implement methods` or `Override methods`.

```
public MyRepository extends CrudRepository<T, Long>{
//in Mac, you press command + N. Then select Override methods.
//in Windows, I don't think Generate Method is given a shortcut. You can find it in the menu bar

}
```

Comment: I don't think it's that simple. There are custom query objects to implement

Comment: Can you give an example of "custom backend"?